# UK (HMRC) Do I need to register as "self employed" if already under Self Assessment

Tags: uk

If I'm already in Self Assessment, and become "self employed" (alongside a job - e.g. selling things on eBay) do I need to specifically register as self employed?

Edited to add: the reason I'm in SA already is due to "complicated" tax affairs, not being self employed previously.

Comment: I was looking at the online Self Employment application form on the gov.uk website and the first few pages of that will give a comprehensive "this applies if..." and "this does not apply if..." advice.  Amazingly, for a government website, it's pretty good and answered a few of my questions even before I put any personal information into it.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit older now - but I see it come up a lot and wanted to answer it 'properly'.

There is a separate process for registering as a sole trader with HMRC in the UK, so yes, you will need to register again.

You do so here: https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader/overview

Generally the HMRC has a bad reputation but I've always found them extremely helpful, including their telephone helpline. It's worth giving them a call if you're in doubt.

Comment: +1 for the useful answer, but you must be extremely lucky. Everyone I've ever spoken to has had terrible experiences with HMRC and I've had endless trouble with them, none of which has been even remotely my fault. They are totally incompetent.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 all the same :) Shame about your bad experiences - I think I must have been incredibly lucky in that case!